# Import xml data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import

i need to import this xml data into mysql database.. i dont have clear idea about it.

this is my .xml file

```
<employee>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">Syed</field>
            <field name="employee_code">101</field>
            <field name="employee_email">syed@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">7412347798</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">21</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">Hari</field>
            <field name="employee_code">102</field>
            <field name="employee_email">hari@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">9895852525</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">23</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">Raja</field>
            <field name="employee_code">103</field>
            <field name="employee_email">raja@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">9956853458</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">23</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">imran</field>
            <field name="employee_code">104</field>
            <field name="employee_email">imran@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">9836052525</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">21</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">Sam</field>
            <field name="employee_code">105</field>
            <field name="employee_email">sam@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">8625852525</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">21</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="employee_name">vinod</field>
            <field name="employee_code">106</field>
            <field name="employee_email">vinod@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="employee_designation">Trainee</field>
            <field name="employee_number">7225852525</field>
            <field name="employee_salary">6000</field>
            <field name="employee_age">24</field>
        </row>
    </employee>
```

my routine for this function is,

```
 if ($file) {
                $handle = simplexml_load_file($file);                           //  Open the file and read
                while($strBookData = fgets($handle, 4096)) {        //  To get Array 
                    $strDatas[] = $strBookData;
                    $strTableColumn = count($strBookData);              // To Get Column count
                }
```

i dont know what to do further.. can any one give me suggestions?? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to get all rows as an array. Just do it in a loop. And then update the table. Like so:

```
while($row = $this->nextRow()) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name, code) VALUES ($row['name']), $row['code']");
}
```

Comment: Never use mysql_query. Use mysqli_query or PDO instead.

Comment: For beginners I would suggest mysql_query its a lot easier. But you are right more object-orientated would be mysqli_query or PDO